# obtained public key, activation code, and blinded key. what now?

Tags: wallets, blockchain, key

After obtaining the activation code from Tezos dot com i then got my blinded key. I can search my public key in the blockchain and find the right amount there, but i cannot figure out why when i try and create a wallet it keeps telling me my balance is 0.

Comment: i think you misunderstood the question. i have my password, my private key, my seed words, AND my blinded key   now what?

Comment: Try it with another wallet software such as Galleon or TezBox. If your data is correct, then it should restore the correct wallet.